# VBA Access CSV import issue from netdrive using shell

Tags: vba, shell, csv, ms-access, import

I have an issue which i can't figure out. 
Quest is to import csv file from a netdrive.

In a basic version files to import were selected automaticaly by code:

```vb
Function FilesAfterDate(Directory As String, FileSpec As String, AfterDate As Date) As String()
    'Requires a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime object lib
    Dim oFS As New FileSystemObject, oFile As File
    Dim listFiles() As String
    Dim i As Long

    i = 0
    If Right(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then Directory = Directory & "\"
    For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder(Directory).files
        If oFile.DateLastModified > AfterDate And oFile.Name Like FileSpec Then
            ReDim Preserve listFiles(i)
            listFiles(i) = oFile.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    FilesAfterDate = listFiles
End Function
```

And then it was imported by code (for each Importfiles(i) where ImportReport = fullpath of Importfiles(i))

```vb
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "ImpSpec_" & sObjSpec & "Csv", "tb" & sObjName & cloneTableNameDesc, ImportReport, False
```

This solution works really slow, so with the help of the users of this portal I've created a shell import:

```vb
fileDetails = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c pushd " & Chr(34) & source_path & Chr(34) & " & forfiles /S /D +" & s_data & " & popd").StdOut.ReadAll, Chr(10))
```

and if I use same import command where ImportReport = fullpath of fileDetails (i) i get an error number 31519.

I used debug.print to check all vartypes, path etc and they are all the same. However sollution with shell doesn't work... Any idea for the reason why?

SOLVED:

As I figure it out - splitting shell function to array somehow doesn't have right data/names for access.

It worked when instead of splitting the shell function i've just assigned it to string value

```vb
full_string_paths = CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c pushd " & Chr(34) & source_path & Chr(34) & " & forfiles /S /D +" & s_data & " & popd").StdOut.ReadAll
```

and then using Mid function and Instr I've created an array of correct filename's

After that everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Error is generating while trying to do DoCmd.TransferText[...]

Comment: I dont know why it appears. I received info that user braX edited it.. normally I dont have it in my code

Comment: Yes, this line.

Comment: What are the values of the arguments 2&3 in in  DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "ImpSpec_" & sObjSpec & "Csv", "tb" & sObjName & cloneTableNameDesc, ImportReport,False. Are they what you expected?  Is the SpecificationName  correct?

Comment: "ImpSpec_" & sObjSpec & "Csv" - it is Import Specification saved in Advanced Import Setup

 "tb" & sObjName & cloneTableNameDesc - it is table name where data should be imported

Comment: Names and everything is correct. I've tried both ways of importing files from arrays. And as i said only "shell" way is not working ;/

Comment: Did you compare `fileDetails` and your function's returned array in the Watch window to check they're "the same"?

Comment: Yes... I checked the filenames, filepaths... all.. everything looks the same however only shell doesn't work...